# Front end lag on React. Is it fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-redux, backend

I am testing my react application on localhost and there seems to be a lag in loading time of about 2 minutes. Based on console outputs, I localized the lag to these lines. Which lines are most likely to cause this lag.

```js
submitNavForm(attribute) {
        if (attribute) {
            fetch(this.grid.urlPrefix + '/api/startNav/' + this.state.bookId + '/' + this.grid.state.sheetName + '/' + attribute)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.navForm.setState({navFormOpen: false, processing: false});
                    this.nav.setState({
                        navOpen: true,
                        sheetName: this.grid.state.sheetName,
                        urlPrefix: this.grid.urlPrefix
                    });
                    this.updateHierFormOption(this.navForm.state.options);
                    this.toolBar.setState({
                        navOpen: true,
                    })
                    this.nav.startNav(data);
                    this.navBar.setState({
                        breadcrumb_ls: [],
                      //  attribute: 0,
                        open: true,
                        navHistoryPathIndex: {},
                        navHistoryTable: {},
                        historyList: [],
                    });
                    this.grid.setState({
                        exploreCol: attribute - 1,
                    })
                    console.log(this.grid)
                    this.nav.brushNlink(this.grid.rowStartIndex, this.grid.rowStopIndex);
                })
```

Edit: Copied the complete function and added the debugger output right after I started to load the page as well as right after the page finished. [image: Right after I started loading the page][image: right after the page finished loading]. The render function's log statement is given by dsgrid.js 233 and it loads instantaneously after line 163 loads on app.js. Render is called through this.nav.startNav on submitNavForm()

Comment: what do your browser's dev tools tell you?

Comment: What happens when you debug this? For instance, when you just put the relevant URL directly into your browser address bar? It sounds like it's taking a **long** time to fetch the data. Alternatively, it could be that you're mistaken that it's the `fetch` and the real problem is rendering once you have the data. Only you can tell, by debugging.

Comment: On dev tools, it looks like the console outputs my log for rendering right after the program finishes fetching. I inserted a console.log operation in render as well, and it doesn't look like that is the lag.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder On dev tools, it looks like the console outputs my log for rendering right after the program finishes fetching. I inserted a console.log operation in render as well, and it doesn't look like that is the lag.

Comment: @DanO The browser dev tools tells me its spending the most time on this line of code

Comment: If you mean that calling `fetch` you see the `console.log` in the final fulfillment handler again quite quickly, that does suggest that it's the rendering that's taking a long time. But it's impossible to say without seeing it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the debugging output as well as the more complete code in the edits. I'm saying that the render function outputs right after the line app.js outputs during fetch so I don't think fetch causes the lag.